# Sass - import variables to be used in mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins

**Is there a way to import external variables into mixins?**
I would like to generate a variablename from a mixin argument
and then call it from an external source. Does this make any sense?

---

### **variables.scss**

```
/* Striped status bar variables ******************************************/

$greyFirstGradientStartColor: #999999;
$greyFirstGradientEndColor: #d3cfcf;
$greySecondGradientStartColor: #ababab;
$greySecondGradientEndColor: #595959;
```

---

### **mixins.scss**

```
@import variables.scss

[...]

@mixin gradient-repeating($color, $deg, $firstWidth, $space, $secondWidth){

  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      $deg,
      $(#{$color}FirstGradientStartColor),
      $(#{$color}FirstGradientEndColor) $firstWidth+px,
      $(#{$color}SecondGradientStartColor) ($firstWidth+$space)+px,
      $(#{$color}SecondGradientStartColor) $secondWidth+px
  );
}
```

---

### **my-main-css-file.scss**

```
@import variables.scss;  
@import mixins.scss;  

[...]

@include gradient-repeating(grey, -45, 20, 0, 20);
```

Comment: This would be amazing if possible. Please post if you find a solution

Comment: did you try this and it didn't work? Or what is your actual problem? I see no reason why this should not [work](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Variable variables do not exist in Sass.  Lists or lists of lists are typically used instead.

Your mixin could be written like this:

```
$grey-gradient: #999999 #d3cfcf, #ababab #595959;

@mixin gradient-repeating($color, $deg, $firstWidth, $space, $secondWidth){
    $firstColor: nth($color, 1);
    $secondColor: nth($color, 2);
    background-image:
        repeating-linear-gradient(
          $deg,
          nth($firstColor, 1),
          nth($firstColor, 2) $firstWidth+px,
          nth($secondColor, 1) ($firstWidth+$space)+px,
          nth($secondColor, 1) $secondWidth+px
        );
}

.foo {
    @include gradient-repeating($grey-gradient, -45, 20, 0, 20);
}
```

Comment: That's clever, I wasn't familiar with the use of lists in Sass. Using lists seems to make for a little obscurity, but the ease of use makes up for it, I'd say. I will use this solution, if I get "OK" from my coding partner to change the project pattern :) Thanks a bunch! (really!)

Comment: For my own coding, I would have written the entire gradient as a variable:  `$grey-gradient: -45deg, #999999, #d3cfcf 20px, #ababab 20px + 0, #595959 20px;`.